# SQL detecting a comment was read

Tags: sql, codeigniter-2

I have a bit of an issue that I'm try to resolve.

I'm trying to put more logic into my sql calls to reduce the amount php has to do. one such place is logic that determines if a user has read a certain message yet. It works but it works too good, here is the SQL:

```
SELECT t.* FROM comment c
LEFT JOIN read_message rm ON c.id-rm.cid
WHERE c.author!=2 AND rm.User=2 AND c.tid=17 AND rm.Topic=17 AND c.Original_Date >=  UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600*24*30 OR c.last_update >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600*24*30
```

the issue is no matter what message id is entered it will always show every record that is considered new, but I want it to only show it if the ids match up.

to simplify what I want:

based on the message id we see if the user read this message already, but if that message is older than 30 days, it is automatically considered old.

the issue is the 30 day math, if i took that portion out it works correctly, but I want it to ignore anything older than 30 days.

I listed codeigniter in the tag as that's the framework I'm using in case you need to know this.

Comment: Did my answer end up helping you, or did you find another solution to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mysql you should be able to use the following SQL to get messages within the last 30 days.

```
SELECT t.* FROM comment c
LEFT JOIN read_message rm ON c.id-rm.cid
WHERE c.author!=2 AND rm.User=2 AND c.tid=17 AND rm.Topic=17 AND
(c.Original_Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW())
OR (c.last_update BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW())
```

Something similar to this should work for your example.

Comment: the issue is it should be something that works on any dbms. otherwise this looks good

Comment: I know that MySQL implements date subtraction differently to SQL Server and likely other DMBS. MySQL uses the DATE_SUB function I showed in my answer. SQL Server uses DATEADD(datepart,number,date) resulting in DATEADD(d,-30,GETDATE()) to subtract 30 from the current date. Hopefully this helps.